# Add image and name to existing WL spl-token

Tags: solana, nft, metaplex, solana-cli, candy-machine

I have always used the `Solana-labs / token-list` repo on Github (https://github.com/solana-labs/token-list) to upload an image and name to the tokens I've created via the console, which was nice and easy. But when I went to upload a new one last night I noticed the repo is read-only as of June 20. I am wondering what the alternative way is to get a name and image associated with my existing WL SPL-token so it doesn't appear as unknown in peoples' wallets.

I've always created whitelist tokens to be used with candy machine in the console with these commands:
`spl-token create-token --decimals 0`
`spl-token create-account <token-key>`
`spl-token mint <token-key> 5 <token-wallet>`

And then used that  as my whitelist key in the config.json.

Is there a way to register the same way somewhere else? The two current options noted in the Readme (https://app.strataprotocol.com/launchpad/manual/new and https://token-creator-lac.vercel.app/) look to help you create a new token that is not already registered. But can I go this route if I want this token to be a Whitelist token used in the Candy Machine?

I think this is my last blocker as of now. I am just wanting to confirm another route that someone knows will work during a live minting to ensure the whitelist works as expected. Any help is appreciated as always.

Comment: I recommend you to see this (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DQbt0-riooo), in how to upload name and logo without using the solana-labs github.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Token-List is deprecated as of *June 20, 2022*.

The process is much simpler now, and it takes seconds rather than hours/days. You need to create new *Token Metadata* using **Metaplex Fungible Token Metadata Standard**: https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/token-standard#the-fungible-standard

You can find the technical details here: https://github.com/jacobcreech/Token-Creator#creating-a-solana-token

For a form-like way to create SPL-tokens, visit StrataProtocol launchpad: https://app.strataprotocol.com/launchpad/manual/new

There is also a demo page built by Jacob Creech: https://token-creator-lac.vercel.app

And yes, using either of the above ways, you can create an SPL-token which can be used as a WL token for you candy machine.

If you already have a token and want to add metadata to it, you can do so as shown here: https://github.com/jacobcreech/Token-Creator#adding-the-token-metadata

Comment: I ended up just using the Strata Launchpad and creating a new token, much easier. If I take the generated mint address and put it into my `config.json` in Candy Machine V2 as the whitelist mint address: `"whitelistMintSettings": {
  "mint": "<Strata generated token address>"
}` I'm assuming that will work the same..only allowing minters with that token to mint during the whitelist.

Comment: Anybody know why a Strata Launchpad generated token would show the name and description inside of a Phantom wallet but does not show the image??

Answer (score 0):

Using Metaplex Fungible Token Metadata Standard i have with the help of a developer friend write a program that can use be used conviently to create metadata and upload your logo details. All you have to do is insert your keypair and Token Address and run the program.
https://github.com/mofrey-max/token-metadata-program/tree/main/mpl these is the repo to source code.
The main.ts is used to update your Logo image Name and Description while the intial.ts is used to create your metadata account and your logo, image, and description.
No need to create a new token just the existing token.

Comment: Hi, I'm a little lost. I was following a tut and at the found out the solana-list was depricated. I've been trying to use https://github.com/mofrey-max/token-metadata-program/tree/main/mpl  but feeling can't figure this out. Are their any instructions/examples? I have my first token on the main-net but can't seem to get the metadata image and name to update? Help?

Comment: If you have created metadata account already you expected to use the main.ts file only. But if not just use the initial.ts. You can visit the repo again to readme file has been update for easy use

Comment: I've forked [mofrey-max/token-metadata-program](https://github.com/mofrey-max/token-metadata-program)  to [BCusack/token-metadata-program](https://github.com/BCusack/token-metadata-program) the main.ts as entry. I added a lot of type def to help and will wrap into a single entry point when I get time.