# How create token at solana with image , and dissabled mint new tokens now?

Tags: solana, solana-cli

I was try search , but old guides say about create token and add it to token list at solana repo , but it now read-only , i try search but all what i find is not working solutions , dead services , and scam services what not allow dissable mint and add self as "token cotroler"

i was try do all from this qustion [Add image and name to existing WL spl-token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72735749/add-image-and-name-to-existing-wl-spl-token)

and try find at google , notting not working. This why i ask about working actual solution, all that outdated.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct you can’t add anything to that list now.

The new way is to update the token metadata account that metaplex provided

There’s more info on it in the metaplex docs but strata has a nice you for doing it too at

https://strataprotocol.com/